# Querying over multiple tables with Sequelize

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

In my code I have multiple Sequelize (using MySQL as a db driver) models like `Car`, `Bike`, `ElectronicPart` that all have a `name` field. Now I'm trying to have a search bar functionality for all of these models, based on their name.
So for example for searching Cars:

```js
Car.findAll({ where: { name: '%search_query%' } })
```

Is there a way to do this for multiple models at once, without having to result to running a query for each model in parallel or generating some sort of master table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The models aren't associated with each other right? Afaik you cant query multiple models in the same findAll method. You'd need to write your own SQL query for it:

```
const { QueryTypes } = require('sequelize')

const results = await sequelize.query('SELECT * FROM Car WHERE name LIKE :search UNION SELECT * FROM Bike WHERE name LIKE :search ... (Other models)',
  { 
    replacements: {search: req.query.search}, 
    type: QueryTypes.SELECT 
  }
)
```

SQL sytnax might be incorrect as I don't use it often, but theoretically you should be able to query all the tables you want and join them into one result using UNION.

Comment: This works, the * needs to be replaced with column names though. I've also used UNION ALL instead of normal UNION because there could be duplicate fields. My solution looks something like this: `SELECT id, name, "car" AS "type" FROM cars WHERE name LIKE :search UNION ALL SELECT id, name, "bike" AS "type" FROM bikes WHERE name LIKE :search...`

Comment: Great, didn't know if you wanted duplicates or not so I left it as the default one and didn't know about the * thing, thought that was supposed to get all columns.